# How to display actual width of the image in the mobile device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I am using infinite slide plugin(https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Infinite-Scroller-Plugin-jQuery.html). It's working perfectly on the desktop with background image but in the mobile device, I have to display full width of the image.
I tried to add some width to the class `.scroll1 li` but I am not getting the all the slider.

Is there any idea how to use the full image on the mobile?
I mean what code I have to use in the media queries?

Would you help me out in this?

**Desktop image**
[image]

**Mobile image.**

[image]

```js
$(function(){
  $('.scroll1').infiniteslide({
   'speed': 100,
   'direction' : 'left',
   'pauseonhover': false
  });
 });
```

```css
   html,body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 .scroll1 {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 .scroll1 img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
 }
 .scroll1 li {
        width: 100%;
         }
 .banner_bg{
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto !important;
      background-position: center;
      min-height:600px;
}

.application_slider_1{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg');
}
.application_slider_2{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://all4desktop.com/data_images/original/4237670-images.jpg');
}
.application_slider_3{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('http://s1.bwallpapers.com/wallpapers/2014/05/09/blue-images_034357941.jpg');
}
.application_slider_4{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url('https://www.bmw.ca/content/dam/bmw/common/all-models/4-series/gran-coupe/2017/images-and-videos/images/BMW-4-series-gran-coupe-images-and-videos-1920x1200-04.jpg.asset.1487328216285.jpg');
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Infinite-Scroller-Plugin-jQuery/infiniteslidev2.js"></script>

<ul class="scroll1">
  <li><div class="application_slider_1 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_2 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_3 banner_bg"></div></li>
  <li><div class="application_slider_4 banner_bg"></div></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: it looks like the background-size property set background-size: contain; on the divs containing the image. Since your images are different heights you might  need to experiment a little bit on the background size propertyto make it look nice.

Comment: @digital-pollution, I tried to set the contain but it's displaying white space on the top and bottom.I need full height of the image.

Comment: there are many options fo the background-size see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp I'm not sure one fits your project the best but you can look up the different options in the provided link and experiment.

Comment: @digital-pollution, I already checked, I tried background-size: 380px 575px; but images are not looking good.

Comment: OK but all your images are different sizes so they wont look good if you fix them to that size. your only options are to crop the sides or fix the height. You won't solve the problem of different sized images and trying to display landscape image in portrait with code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-height with vh value, like so:

```
.banner_bg{
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            background-position: center;
            min-height:60vh;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but sorry It's not working. I have to display the height 100% so it will cover the mobile screen and I need a full width of the image, not 100% because If I set 100% of the width then it will fit the mobile screen just like I am getting the output. I need a full image to be a scroll like a desktop.